# Customizing coredns on k3s to point a domain directly to the cluster loadbalancer

Tags: kubernetes, coredns, k3s

I'm trying to add a rewrite to coredns to point a domain to the cluster loadbalancer (so that the request for that domain gets redirected back into the cluster). I can't seem to find a way to affect k3s' coredns configuration. Is there a way to change it?

(This is to work around https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/1292#issuecomment-757283796 where a pod tries to contact another service in the cluster via a DNS name that points to the router's IP, which fails due to how NAT works.)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to configure `CoreDNS` to mapping one domain to another domain by adding `rewrite` rule.
Suppose you have domain `example.com` and you want that domain to point to `google.com` domain.

To do this in `CoreDNS`, you can use the `rewrite` plugin.

Configuration of `CoreDNS` is stored in `coredns` `ConfigMap` in `kube-system` namespace.
You can edit it using:

```
root@kmaster:~# kubectl edit cm coredns -n kube-system
```

Just add one `rewrite` rule, like in the example below:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health
        rewrite name example.com google.com # mapping example.com to google.com
        ready
...
```

Next you need to reload `CoreDNS`, to use new configuration. You may delete coredns `Pod` (`coredns` is deployed as `Deployment`, so new `Pod` will be created) or you can send it a `SIGUSR1` to tell it to reload graceful.

Finally we can check how it works:

```
root@kmaster:~# kubectl run -it --rm --image=infoblox/dnstools:latest dnstools
dnstools# host -t A google.com
google.com has address 172.217.21.238
dnstools# host -t A example.com
example.com has address 172.217.21.238
```

You can find more information about rewrite plugin in [Coredns rewrite documentation](https://coredns.io/plugins/rewrite/).

Comment: Modifying the `coredns` ConfigMap is not robust across k3s updates, as its manifest from `/var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/manifests/coredns.yaml` can be reapplied at any time, thus clearing any modifications made to the ConfigMap in-situ.

Customizations should be added to a new `coredns-custom` ConfigMap, and CoreDNS will pick it up automatically.